# Mapbox outdoor map not working

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I'm able to use mapbox standard and satellite tiles with no problem, and can switch back and forth between the layers. But when I try and use the outdoor layers, I get a 401 error. Here is where I set up the layers:

```
var mapLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.streets',
  accessToken: '<mytoken>'
}),    
satLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.satellite',
  accessToken: '<mytoken>'
}), 
terrainLayer = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/outdoors-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}??access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  id: 'mapbox.outdoors',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/p-craig-peddie/<styletoken>',
  accessToken: '<mytoken>'
});  

var baseMaps = {
  "Default": mapLayer,
  "Terrain": terrainLayer,
  "Satellite": satLayer
};

  var map = L.map('leafletMap', {
    center: [33.559768, -117.728416],
    zoom: 8,
    layers: [mapLayer, polyLayer, gridLayer]
  });
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Double question mark '??' in the URL was the culprit. Duh.